# Polymorphic Mapping of Collections with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-5

TL;DR: I'm having trouble with Polymorphic mapping. I've made a github repo with a test suite that illustrates my issue. Please find it here: [LINK TO REPO](https://github.com/780Farva/AutoMapperInquiry)

I'm working on implementing a save/load feature. To accomplish this, I need to make sure the domain model that I'm serializing is represented in a serialization-friendly way. To accomplish this I've created a set of DTOs that contain the bare-minimum set of information required to do a meaningful save or load.

Something like this for the domain:

```
public interface IDomainType
{
  int Prop0 { get; set; }
}

public class DomainType1 : IDomainType
{
  public int Prop1 { get; set; }
  public int Prop0 { get; set; }
}

public class DomainType2 : IDomainType
{
  public int Prop2 { get; set; }
  public int Prop0 { get; set; }
}

public class DomainCollection
{
  public IEnumerable<IDomainType> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

...and for the DTOs

```
public interface IDto
{
  int P0 { get; set; }
}

public class Dto1 : IDto
{
  public int P1 { get; set; }
  public int P0 { get; set; }
}

public class Dto2 : IDto
{
  public int P2 { get; set; }
  public int P0 { get; set; }
}

public class DtoCollection
{
  private readonly IList<IDto> entries = new List<IDto>();
  public IEnumerable<IDto> Entries => this.entries;
  public void Add(IDto entry) { this.entries.Add(entry); }
}
```

The idea is that DomainCollection represents the current state of the application. The goal is that mapping DomainCollection to DtoCollection results in an instance of DtoCollection that contains the appropriate implementations of IDto as they map to the domain. And vice versa.

A little extra trick here is that the different concrete domain types come from different plugin assemblies, so I need to find an elegant way to have AutoMapper (or similar, if you know of a better mapping framework) do the heavy lifting for me.

Using structuremap, I'm already able to locate and load all the profiles from the plugins and configure the applications IMapper with them.

I've tried to create the profiles like this...

```
public class CollectionMappingProfile : Profile
{
  public CollectionMappingProfile()
  {
    this.CreateMap<IDomainType, IDto>().ForMember(m => m.P0, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.Prop0)).ReverseMap();

    this.CreateMap<DtoCollection, DomainCollection>().
       ForMember(fc => fc.Entries, opt => opt.Ignore()).
       AfterMap((tc, fc, ctx) => fc.Entries = tc.Entries.Select(e => ctx.Mapper.Map<IDomainType>(e)).ToArray());

    this.CreateMap<DomainCollection, DtoCollection>().
       AfterMap((fc, tc, ctx) =>
                {
                  foreach (var t in fc.Entries.Select(e => ctx.Mapper.Map<IDto>(e))) tc.Add(t);
                });
}

public class DomainProfile1 : Profile
{
  public DomainProfile1()
  {
    this.CreateMap<DomainType1, Dto1>().ForMember(m => m.P1, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.Prop1))
      .IncludeBase<IDomainType, IDto>().ReverseMap();
  }
}

public class DomainProfile2 : Profile
{
  public DomainProfile2()
  {
    this.CreateMap<DomainType2, IDto>().ConstructUsing(f => new Dto2()).As<Dto2>();

    this.CreateMap<DomainType2, Dto2>().ForMember(m => m.P2, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.Prop2))
      .IncludeBase<IDomainType, IDto>().ReverseMap();
  }
}
```

I then wrote a test suite to make sure that the mapping will behave as expected when its time to integrate this feature with the application. I found whenever DTOs were getting mapped to Domain (think Load) that AutoMapper would create proxies of IDomainType instead of resolving them to the domain.

I suspect the problem is with my mapping profiles, but I've run out of talent. Thanks in advance for your input.

[Here's another link to the github repo](https://github.com/780Farva/AutoMapperInquiry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a little time reorganizing the repo. I went as far as to mimic a core project and two plugins. This made sure that I wouldn't end up with a false-positive result when the tests finally started passing.

What I found was that the solution had two(ish) parts to it.

1) I was abusing AutoMapper's .ReverseMap() configuration method. I was assuming that it would perform the reciprocal of whatever custom mapping I was doing. Not so! It only does simple reversals. Fair enough. Some SO questions/answers about it: 
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560936/automapper-reversemap-does-not-perform-mapping), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490456/automapper-bidirectional-mapping-with-reversemap-and-formember)

2) I wasn't fully defining the mapping inheritance properly. I'll break it down.

2.1) My DomainProfiles followed this pattern:

```
public class DomainProfile1 : Profile
{
  public DomainProfile1()
  {
    this.CreateMap<DomainType1, IDto>().ConstructUsing(f => new Dto1()).As<Dto1>();
    this.CreateMap<DomainType1, Dto1>().ForMember(m => m.P1, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.Prop1))
      .IncludeBase<IDomainType, IDto>().ReverseMap();

    this.CreateMap<Dto1, IDomainType>().ConstructUsing(dto => new DomainType1()).As<DomainType1>();
  }
}
```

So now knowing that .ReverseMap() is not the thing to use here, it becomes obvious that the map between Dto1 and DomainType1 was poorly defined. Also, The mapping between DomainType1 and IDto didn't link back to the base IDomainType to IDto mapping. Also an issue. The final result:

```
public class DomainProfile1 : Profile
{
  public DomainProfile1()
  {
    this.CreateMap<DomainType1, IDto>().IncludeBase<IDomainType, IDto>().ConstructUsing(f => new Dto1()).As<Dto1>();
    this.CreateMap<DomainType1, Dto1>().IncludeBase<DomainType1, IDto>().ForMember(m => m.P1, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.Prop1));

    this.CreateMap<Dto1, IDomainType>().IncludeBase<IDto, IDomainType>().ConstructUsing(dto => new DomainType1()).As<DomainType1>();
    this.CreateMap<Dto1, DomainType1>().IncludeBase<Dto1, IDomainType>().ForMember(m => m.Prop1, a => a.MapFrom(x => x.P1));
  }
}
```

Now each direction of the mapping is explicitly defined, and the inheritance is respected.

2.2) The most base mapping for IDomainType and IDto was inside of the profile that also defined the mappings for the "collection" types. This meant that once I had split up the project to mimic a plugin architecture, the tests that only tested the simplest inheritances failed in new ways - The base mapping couldn't be found. All I had to do was put these mappings into their own profile and use that profile in the tests as well. That's just good [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I'll apply what I've learned to my actual project before I mark my own answer as the accepted answer. Hopefully I've got it and hopefully this will be helpful to others.

Useful links:

[this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays)

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456519/how-to-configure-automapper-for-polymorphism-with-explicit-member-mapping) was a good refactoring exercise. I admittedly used it as a starting place to build up my example. So, thanks @Olivier.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this question when looking in to a polymorphic mapping issue myself. The answer is good, but just another option if you'd like to approach it from the base mapping perspective and have many derived classes, you can try the following:

```
CreateMap<VehicleEntity, VehicleDto>()
    .IncludeAllDerived();

CreateMap<CarEntity, CarDto>();
CreateMap<TrainEntity, TrainDto>();
CreateMap<BusEntity, BusDto>();
```

See the [automapper docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html) for more info.